# Slick2D - Could not locate OpenAL library (Netbeans)

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm using netbeans 7.2.1, Java 7, Slick2D and LWJGL 2.8.5
when I'm running my game with NetBeans (F6) it's showing me "Could not locate OpenAL library"
but, when I build my program (F11) and running the jar file, the sound is working well

How do I fix it? :(
this is how I'm using the sound

Creating variable

```
private Sound select_sound;
```

Setting a value

```
this.select_sound = new Sound(ProgramConstant.MENU_DIR + "sounds/select.wav");
```

Playing the sound

> this.select_sound.play();

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Did you follow the [10 step (official) tutorial](http://www.slick2d.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_Slick2D_with_NetBeansIDE) to set up Slick2D on Netbeans?

Comment: @asermax, sure I did...